# Show that $\dfrac{2^p}{p}$ has remainder of $2$ for any prime $p \geq 3$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

A bonus question on my last math exam I haven't been able to solve. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 11):

Hint: Fermat's Little Theorem.

If you cannot or don't wish to directly employ that, you can consider the binomial expansion of $2^p = (1+1)^p$.

Comment: Hmm, true. But then you must prove, that each occuring binomial-coefficient (except the first and the last) is divisible by p. Surely not too difficult again, but I think the OP goes into the direction to try to understand Fermat's little theorem at all...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Yes, I know, and I was prepared to guide OP through that should he have asked. Oh well, it's not too difficult to post here. Consider the general binomial coefficient $n = \binom{p}{r} = \frac{p!}{r!(p-r)!} = p\cdot \frac{(p-1)!}{r!(p-r)!}$. Call that expression $p\cdot \frac ab$. We now have $p\cdot \frac ab = n$, giving $pa = nb$. $p|(pa) \implies p|(nb)$. Now since $p$ is prime, $p \nmid b$ for $r \neq 0,p$. Hence $p|n$, as required. So every binomial coefficient except the first and last is divisible by $p$. What's left is just $1^p + 1^p \equiv 2 \pmod p$.

Comment: :-)    (some additional characters....)

Answer (score 0):

Fermat's little theorem is probably the best way to go here. Try to avoid it and you'll probably waste some time reinventing the wheel.

If $\gcd(b, p) = 1$ and $p$ is prime, then $b^{p - 1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$. This is Fermat's little theorem, it doesn't need to be proven again, but you can certainly look up a proof of it if you don't want to take my word for it.

So, if $p$ is an odd prime, then obviously $\gcd(2, p) = 1$. This means that $2^{p - 1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$. Since $1 \times 2 = 2$, this means that $2^p \equiv 2 \pmod p$.